# Hibernate many-to-many - Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate

I'm having an issue reusing records to populate a cross reference table. Hibernate attempts to update the foreign key records instead of populating the cross reference table.

Inserting new records work fine.

DB Diagram
[image]

When I add new locations and link them in the cross-reference table, it works without any issues:

```
//Get specific object
TestContainer tc = (TestContainer) session.createQuery("from TestContainer where id = :id")
        .setParameter("id", id).list().get(0);

//Locations
Set<TestContainerLocation> tcl = new HashSet<TestContainerLocation>();

TestContainerLocation loc1 = new TestContainerLocation();
loc1.setLocationName("String1"); 
TestContainerLocation loc2 = new TestContainerLocation();
loc2.setLocationName("String2");

tcl.add(loc1);
tcl.add(loc2);

tc.setTestContainerLocation(tcl);

session.saveOrUpdate(tc);
```

When I attempt to reuse existing locations, then it doesn't go through. Instead of inserting into the cross reference table, it attempts to update the foreign key table by providing a null value, which fails due to the constraints.

```
//Get specific object
TestContainer tc = (TestContainer) session.createQuery("from TestContainer where id = :id")
        .setParameter("id", id).list().get(0);

Set<TestContainerLocation> tcl = new HashSet<TestContainerLocation>();

TestContainerLocation loc1 = new TestContainerLocation();
loc1.setLocationId(1);//existing Id 
TestContainerLocation loc2 = new TestContainerLocation();
loc2.setLocationId(2);//existing Id

tcl.add(loc1);
tcl.add(loc2);

tc.setTestContainerLocation(tcl);

session.saveOrUpdate(tc);
```

Error:

```
Hibernate: select testcontai0_.id as id0_, testcontai0_.step_one as step2_0_, testcontai0_.step_two as step3_0_, testcontai0_.step_three as step4_0_, testcontai0_.type_id as type5_0_ from test_container testcontai0_ where testcontai0_.id=?
Hibernate: update test_container_location set location_name=? where location_id=?
Hibernate: update test_container_location set location_name=? where location_id=?
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'location_name' cannot be null
```

MAPPINGS

TestContainer.hbm.xml

```
<class name="TestContainer"
    table="test_container">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="stepOne" type="string" length="255" column="step_one" not-null="false" />
    <property name="stepTwo" type="integer" column="step_two" not-null="false" />
    <property name="stepThree" type="string" length="255" column="step_three" not-null="false" />

    <many-to-one name="testContainerType" class="org.test.data.TestContainerType" fetch="select">
        <column name="type_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>

    <set name="testContainerLocation" table="test_container_location_lookup"
     inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="org.test.data.TestContainerLocation">
            <column name="location_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>

</class>
```

TestContainerLocation.hbm.xml

```
    <class name="TestContainerLocation"
        table="test_container_location">
        <id name="locationId" column="location_id" type="integer" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="locationName" type="string" length="255" column="location_name" not-null="false" />

        <set name="testContainer" table="test_container_location_lookup"
         inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="location_id" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="org.test.data.TestContainer">
                <column name="id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
```

Comment: You're not updating the location name associated with the `location_name` column in your database which is mandatory.

Comment: @Lion since I'm setting the Id that I want, why is it doing an update of the foreign key table? Shouldn't it simply add the records in the cross reference table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `session.get()` or `load()` instead of `new TestContainerLocation()`. For example:

```
TestContainerLocation loc1 = (TestContainerLocation) session.load(TestContainerLocation.class, 1);
```

**EDIT**: Hibernate tries to update the `TestContainerLocation` entity when you use `new()` and then set the id.

Answer (score 0):

> this error coused by your default string size character
>   you have two choice for solve this problem
>   1.you must up string character size
>   example

```
<property name="companyname" column="company_name" length='25' />
```

> your companyname size must little than 25
>    2. change type to text
>   example

```
<property name="companyname" column="company_name" type='text' />
```